# Using LINQ, how can I limit rows retrieved depending on a child table property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have the following two classes:

```
public class Word 
{
    public System.Guid WordId { get; set; } // WordId (Primary key)
    public string Name { get; set; } // Name (length: 20)
    // Reverse navigation
    public virtual System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<WordForm> WordForms { get; set; } // WordForm.FK_WordFormWord 
}

public class WordForm
{
    public System.Guid WordFormId { get; set; } // WordFormId (Primary key)
    public System.Guid WordId { get; set; } // WordId
    public int         SourceId { get; set; } // Source
    public string Definition { get; set; } // Definition (length: 500)
    // Foreign keys
    public virtual Word Word { get; set; } // FK_WordFormWord
}
```

I have this code that returns only those words that are not in wordForm:

```
var words = db.Words
            .Where(w => !db.WordForms.Any(z => z.WordId == w.WordId))
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();
```

How can I change this so it retrieve words that are not in wordForm and having a sourceId of 2.

In other words

- If there's the word `house` and it has a SourceId of 1 in wordForm then I want to include this in words
- If there's a word `house` and it has a SourceId of 2 in wordForm then I don't want to include this in words

Comment: Since WordForms is a virtual property of Word, couldn't you just do something like this: 
var words = db.Words.WordForms.Where(x => x.SourceId == 2);

Comment: @RickySanchez - could you show me how I could fit that into my current LINQ. I tried adding this but no luck:  .Where(w => db.WordForms.Where(x => x.SourceId == 2))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate solution:

1) Get all WordIds from WordForms which have source id as 2

```
HashSet<Guid> wordFromIdListWithNeededSourceId =
          new HashSet<Guid>
            (
                db.WordForms.Where(wf => wf.SourceId == 2)
                .Select(wf => wf.WordId).Distinct()
            );
```

2) Get all Words which don't have any WordForms from above

```
List<Word> words = db.Words
    .Where(wf => !wordFromIdListWithNeededSourceId
    .Contains(wf.WordId)).AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this if it works.

```
var words = db.Words
            .Where(w => !db.WordForms.Any(z => z.WordId == w.WordId) && db.WordForms.Any(y => y.SourceId == 2))
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();
```

**P.S** I have not compiled and checked!!

Comment: @SamanthaJ IF you get the solution then please mark it as answer or if yourselves have got it work then plz share the solution :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the following, I prefer this as it is a easier to read:

```
var words = db.Words
            .Where(w => !db.WordForms.Any(z => z.WordId == w.WordId)) // Words that aren't in WordForms
            .Where(w => db.WordForms.Any(x => x.SourceId == 2)) //Words with a Source Id of 8
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();
```

You might have to change it slightly to make sure it compiles as I didn't test it. However, the example above using multiple `Where` statements should get you in the right direction.